# How to search by arbitrary fields using field selector with kubectl?

Tags: linux, shell, docker, kubernetes, kubectl

In this [doc](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/field-selectors/#supported-fields) supported fields are not listed and I cannot find them properly. With some trial and experiments I noticed the following:

This works nicely and finds some pods:

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=spec.restartPolicy=Never
```

But this produces error:

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=spec.serviceAccount=default

No resources found.
Error from server (BadRequest): Unable to find {"" "v1" "pods"} that match label selector "", field selector "spec.serviceAccount=default": field label not supported: spec.serviceAccount
```

So how is this decided? I know I can find with JSONPath but it is client-side filtering AFAIK.

Comment: Many people does development with Kubernetes, Docker, etc. and there are thousands of Docker and Kubernetes questions here and there is not another a good place for them in the StackExchange network, neither Server is a good candidate and there are obviously more people here. Voting close on an already answered question is nothing but a hostile action. Micro-management of questions in StackOverfow is discouraging many people and leads to elitist behavior as mentioned here https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/04/26/stack-overflow-isnt-very-welcoming-its-time-for-that-to-change/

Comment: You should complain on [Meta.SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/). Closing off-topic questions is a standard workflow on Stack Overflow. There's nothing hostile about it. Also, the "elitist behavior" concerns community interactions with inexperienced programmers and minority groups. It has nothing to do with off-topic fodder.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select the `serviceAccount` using following query:

```
kubectl get pods --field-selector=spec.serviceAccountName="default"
```

The `--field-selector` currently selects only equality based values and in that too it has very limited support to select the pod based on fields. The following fields are supported by `--field-selector`:

```
metadata.name
metadata.namespace
spec.nodeName
spec.restartPolicy
spec.schedulerName
spec.serviceAccountName
status.phase
status.podIP
status.nominatedNodeName
```

As you already know, you need to rely on the jsonpath to select any other field other than above fields.

You can visit following link to find out more:

> https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/core/v1/conversion.go#L160-L167][1](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/core/v1/conversion.go#L160-L167)